# contractions in Google Natural Language

Tags: google-cloud-nl

I'm using cloud NL to analyze text from Google Speech and it seems to be having trouble with tokenizing contractions
for example

> "I don't like you"

comes back as tokens whose content_text are:

> "I" "do" "n't" "like" "you"

escaping quotes did not help, in this case it came back as

> "I" "don" "\'t" "like" "you"

but I found that removing apos' did and the tokens

> I dont like you

came back with "dont" as a verb (correct enough)

Is this the correct workaround for now?

Comment: Why do you consider the response `"I" "do" "n't" "like" "you"` incorrect?  The token `"n't"` seems correctly identified as the contracted form of "not".  For example you can put the text in the Try The API text box on [this page](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/) and click the Syntax tab to see the parsed syntax.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/don't

Comment: I see - depending on your actual application it might or might not be what you want.  For instance you probably want "they're" to be split up as two tokens: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/they're

Comment: Not in some cases, for example if I'm passing the token text to a text-to-speech service or otherwise rendering it to be user-visible.

Comment: Out curiosity, why do you want to send the tokens to the text-to-speech service instead of the original text?

Comment: TBH it's an artifact of my early design and I've been thinking the same thing.  I'm going to pass the original text alongside the language results and render that.